# Ошибка "expression(stream!=null)"

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться в ошибке. Во время работы программы выскакивает следующая ошибка:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
program:d\aes_cpu_dec\debug\fij.exe
file:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\fread.c
line:102

Expression:(stream!=NULL)
```

Код функции:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rijndael.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define bufsize 160000
#define KEYBITS 256
unsigned char bufin[bufsize], bufout[bufsize];

int main(int argc, char * fname)
{
    unsigned long rk[RKLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
    unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
    int i;
    int nrounds, realreads;
    char password[80], sfname[80], dfname[80];
    FILE *input, *output;
    unsigned char plaintext[16];
    unsigned char ciphertext[16];
    clock_t t1,t2;
    float tm;
    /*  if (argc < 3)
    {
        fputs("Missing argument", stderr);
        return 1;
    }*/
    printf("enter key: ");
    gets_s(password);
    printf("enter src file name: ");
    gets_s(sfname);
    printf("enter dst file name: ");
    gets_s(dfname);
    t1=clock();
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(key); i++)
        key[i] = *password != 0 ? (*password)++ : 0;
    input = fopen(sfname, "rb");
    output=fopen(dfname, "wb");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        fputs("File read error", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    nrounds = rijndaelSetupDecrypt(rk, key, 256);
    // do
    {
        realreads=fread(bufin,1,bufsize,input); // ошибка выскакивает в этом месте
        printf ("Error open file (%s): %s\n", sfname, strerror(errno));
        if(realreads<bufsize)
        memset(&bufin[realreads],0,bufsize-realreads);
        int j=0;
        while(j<=realreads){
            for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
            {
                ciphertext[i]=bufin[i+j];
            }
            rijndaelDecrypt(rk, nrounds, ciphertext, plaintext);
            for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
            {
                bufout[i+j]=plaintext[i];
            }
            j+=16;
        }
        int towrite=realreads;
        if((realreads%16)!=0)
        {
            towrite/=16;
            towrite+=1;
            towrite*=16;
        }
        fwrite(bufout,1,towrite,output);
    }
    //while(realreads==bufsize);
        t2=clock();
    tm=(float)(t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("t=%f\n",tm);
    fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: И что конкретно непонятно в сообщении об ошибке? Тем более что отмечена строка, на которой она выдаётся (подсказка: не нужно было убирать проверку if(input==NULL)...)

Comment: даже если рас комментировать данные строчки ошибка все равно выдается 
if (input == NULL)
{
fputs("File read error", stderr);
return 1;
}

Comment: @sergey88, Вы же **сами пишите**, что ошибка выдается

    fputs("File read error", stderr);

значит файл не открывается и незачем пытаться что-то делать дальше, тем более закомментировав **этот** выход из программы.

Думаю, вместо puts() лучше поствить 

    printf ("Error open file (%s): %s\n", sfname, strerror(errno));

по крайней мере увидите более осмысленное сообщение (с распечатанным именем файла)

Comment: скажите если после выполнения программы отображается время 0.566000 с использованием CLOCKS_PER_SEC, это значит что программа выполнилась за 566 миллисекунд